# Unexpected jBoss crash and auditing signals

Tags: linux, signals, auditd

We're experiencing unexpected JBoss crashes on a semi-regular basis. JBoss 5 is running on RHEL6 in this case.

I believe this is related to a sigusr1 sent to the JBoss process. The JBoss server logs simply end, nothing is logged at all regarding the shutdown. Manually sending sigusr1 reproduces the problem.

My question is what is the best way to determine what is sending this signal. Is it possible to use auditd to somehow trap these and log the sender?

Other suggestions for protecting the process from signals, what may randomly be sending sigusr1's on a RHEL6 machine or auditing and logging signals welcome.

Thanks

Comment: My first question in cases like this is always "is SELinux enabled?".

Comment: SELinux is currently disabled; enabling it in permissive mode is an option.